# ¿Se puede hacer un select dependiente tan sólo utilizando datos de una misma tabla?

Tags: java, html, oracle, jsp

me surgió una duda ya que estoy relizando un formulario web en HTML que haga una búsqueda de datos mediante  conectado a una BD en Oracle, pero sólo tengo una tabla para la búsqueda siendo esta

```
CREATE TABLE "OCEXPNP"."OCEX_UEA" 
(   "ID_UEA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "N_DEP" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "N_PROV" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "N_DIST" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE )
```

Es posible hacerlo con una sola tabla o tengo que desplegarla creando una tabla para departamento(n_dep), provincia(n_prov) y distrito(n_dist).

En mi primer select para listar los Departamentos lo tengo así:

```
<select id="n_dep">
<% ConectaDB con=new ConectaDB();
  try{
   con.conectar();
   String sql="select unique(NOMBRE_DPTO) from c_departamento order by NOMBRE_DPTO asc";
   con.st=con.conexion.createStatement(); 
   con.rt=con.st.executeQuery(sql);

  while (con.rt.next()){
    out.println("<option value=con.rt.getString(ID_DPTO)>"+con.rt.getString("NOMBRE_DPTO")+"</option>");
   }
 }catch(Exception e){                                                        
    out.print(e.toString()); 
 }
%>
</select>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

si los creas todos en una sola tabla, no estaria normalizada la tabla, ya que exitirian campos inecesarios y ademas seria una tabla gigantesca, es decir, asi como lo tienes por cada provincia tendrias tantos registros como distritos tengas y ademas por cada departamento tendrias registros tantos como provincias tengas... y asi sucesivamente....

te recomiento mejor terner una tabla para cada uno y asi almacenas los ids... es mucho mas facil y practico.

espero te surva... By: JJ

//aqui pones el valor de las variables...
var parametros = { 'llave' : valor }
 $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        //la ruta absoluta que vas a enviar
        url:   'URL/destino.php',
        //el metodo por el cual debes enviar 
        type:  "post",
        success:  function (response) {
          //aqui ejecutas cuando llegue una buena respuesta
                console.log(response);
        },
        //en caso de errores, haces algo
        error : function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
    },
}
});

aqui te dejo un pequeño ejemplo en el cual te puedes basar, espero te sirva Bro...

Comment: El problema es que trabajan así, con esa tabla única, habría una solución para poder crear esos select dependientes, podría pasar como parámetro el "n_dep" declarando como id en el select?

Comment: en teoria si puedes hacerlo de manera que cuando creas el primer select en el value no gurades el ID del departamento sino su nombre, y en el momento que rellenas el otro select capturas el valor (nombre) y cuando consultes esa tabla en donde tenes todos los datos usas ese valor en el where y asi te traeria todos los registros asociados a ese departamento

Comment: Claro en teoría sí, pero ahora pasando a la práctica tan sólo haría toda la programación en el mismo jsp o tendría que usar ajax o javascript?

Comment: yo lo haria todo con javascript y ajax, ya que el jsp es compilado desde el servidor, por ende cuando se cargue la paguna el jsp ya se debe haber cargado.

Comment: tendrás algun ejemplo en ajax? es que no manejo mucho sobre ello, igual gracias por darme un camino de como avanzar con esto.

Comment: ok dame un momento te pongo un ejemplo de ajax

Comment: Dale, te espero